# How do I make my PHP web service return a 500 when it's slow?

Tags: php, apache

My web service is really fast, but people sometimes complain that it times out for some unknown glitchy reason. Is there some header or something I can put at the top of the script that will return a 500 and terminate any server side processes if the script takes longer than,say, 2 seconds?

Comment: I don't think you should ever knowingly want to return a 500, surely a 503 would be more suitable if you were to ever go down this route (which sounds like an inherently bad idea anyway)

Comment: Interesting. Why is it a bad idea to return the correct http code? If there's a server error or a timeout, why not reply with that information?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're coming at this from the wrong angle - if you were to do something like this, what makes you think that the 500 error wouldn't be 'glitchy' too and sometimes not trigger or the script would still time out?

Technically you probably could achieve something using php's `register_tick_function()` but I would suggest if you're not certain what the cause of the original glitch is you should be looking at logging / debugging / resolving that as a more sustainable solution.

If for example the timeout is related to server load, connectivity/network timeouts etc I doubt your work-around would be worth the effort in writing it.